how to make bend modifier affecting from parent to child which has physics applied?
the question is in the title, please help!
The bend modifier is set to the DNA helix string. I want the two strings to split while the attached flags with physics are still on it.
First I tried with a simple parent set to an empty in which my flag is hooked. But it wasn't moving at all. After that I've set parent to vertex(triangle). The hooked verticies are moving but the physics is not working now.
How can I make this work?


hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/
